# I need an alert message when closing the browser window (when clicked on X button of browser)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0

I need an alert message when I close the browser `close(X)` button.

I googled on this issue, but answers are using `onbeforeunload()` method in body tag of the form.

But when I am using master page contained forms there is no body tag to call this method. In this case what I should do? Without using body tag in the form.

When I am using this `onbeforeunload()` in body tag, but when I clicked refresh button of the page this alert message firing. This alert message not fired when refresh button clicked on the browser. And this is not working in chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function ()
 {

     alert("WINDOW IS CLOSED");

};
```

Comment: Sorry to say but its working for all the browsers in my system

Comment: not working sir. when i clicked on refresh button (F5), alert message firing. my intention is when closed the browser close button, then only firing the alert message not for refreshing.

Comment: I have used it on live project